# Валидация vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет,написал авторизацию,и пару проверок написано в таком виде

```
passwordRules: [
          v => !!v || 'Обязательное поле',
          v => (v && v.length >= 6) || 'Password must be equal or more than 6 characters'
    ]
```

подскажите как написать проверку на введение одних пробелов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что-то из этого подойдёт:

```
v => /\S/.test(v) || "Нужно чтобы хотя бы один символ не был пробельным"
```

```
v => /^\s+$/.test(v) && "Нужно чтобы хотя бы один символ не был пробельным"
```

Comment: /\S/.test(v) ,я думаю так

Comment: Да, перепутал. Исправил.

Answer (score 1):

```
!!v.trim() || "Нужно чтобы хотя бы один символ не был пробельным"
```

Comment: Перенёс обсуждение `!!` [в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81605/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-gs-d).